# Sorting a list in C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Record
{
    public string host { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string RunAsUser { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string StartMode { get; set; }
}
```

And a list of this class:

```
List<Record> Records = new List<Record>();
```

This list contains a number of entries. How can I sort this list on the basis of `Record.host` (alphabetically) ?

Is there a built-in function, or would I need to write my own? If so, could someone point me in the right direction by perhaps giving me some pseudo-code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can sort them using Linq if you just need to iterate them in sorted order.

```
Records.OrderBy(r => r.host)
```

Otherwise, you could call:

```
Records.sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.host, y.host));
```

To permanently sort the list.

Comment: As long as you want ascending order.  Also: `List<Record> acending = descending.OrderBy(x => x.host).ThenBy(x => x.name).ToList();`

Answer (score 2):

The following will sort the list itself:

```
Records.Sort((a, b) => String.Compare(a.host, b.host));
```

Comment: Note; it would be safer to use `string.Compare(a.host,b.host)` - then if `a.host` is `null` you don't have to worry about it.